# How to calculate average or sum using data from a Ballerina table with query expressions?

Tags: ballerina

I have a Ballerina table (`table<Student> key(subject,studentId)`) with fields such as *studentId, subject, marks*. Marks are given for each subject.

I need to,

1. Find the average/sum of each student and construct another table
2. Rank the students(sort by the student scores).

How can I do them with query expressions in Ballerina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `group by` clause in query expressions to calculate the average and sum and the `order by` clause to rank the students. Below is an example demonstration.

Take `subjectScores` as the `table` containing subject and score details.

```
type SubjectScore record {|
    readonly string subject;
    readonly string studentId;
    int score;
|};

table<SubjectScore> key(subject, studentId) subjectsScores = table [
        {subject: "A", studentId: "1", score: 100},
        {subject: "A", studentId: "2", score: 90},
        {subject: "A", studentId: "3", score: 80},
        {subject: "B", studentId: "1", score: 80},
        {subject: "B", studentId: "2", score: 70},
        {subject: "B", studentId: "3", score: 60},
        {subject: "C", studentId: "1", score: 60},
        {subject: "C", studentId: "2", score: 50},
        {subject: "C", studentId: "3", score: 40}
    ];
```

We can have a new table defined to enter the total scores and average scores of each student by grouping the above table entries by `studentId` and then rank the students according to the scores using `order by`.

```
type ProcessedScore record {|
    readonly string studentId;
    int totalScore;
    decimal averageScore;
|};

public function main() returns error? {
    ProcessedScore[] processedScores =
        from var {studentId, score} in subjectsScores
            group by studentId
            select {studentId, totalScore: sum(score), averageScore: avg(score)};

    ProcessedScore[] rankedStudents = from ProcessedScore score in processedScores
        order by score.totalScore descending
        select score;
}
```

`rankedStudents` would contain the following results.

```
[{"studentId":"1","totalScore":240,"averageScore":80},
{"studentId":"2","totalScore":210,"averageScore":70},
{"studentId":"3","totalScore":180,"averageScore":60}]
```